# formatting the output for an SQL query

Tags: python

I have the following script where I use an SQL query to get the required information,it works fine but the information is not in expected format,please see below for expected output,it should be space seperated list with no new characters ("\n") at the end,how to get the output in the required format?

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="dbhost",user="username",port=3339,passwd="passwordname",db="dbname")
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()            
gerritlist = []
# Prepare SQL query to get the gerrits from the database.
sql_get = """SELECT gerrit_id
            FROM dbname.gerrit_submit_table
            where (SI='%s'
            and component='%s')"""%(SI,component)

#print sql_get
rows = cursor.execute(sql_get)  
gerrits = cursor.fetchall() 
print "GERRITS FROM DB"
print gerrits
```

OUTPUT:-

```
 GERRITS FROM DB
(('1258565',), ('1279604',))
```

EXPECTEDOUTPUT:-(space seperated list ,no new character(\n) at the end)

```
  1258565 1279604
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, just do this:

```
print ' '.join(item[0] for item in gerrits),
```

or this:

```
print ' '.join(item[0] for item in gerrits).rstrip('\r\n')
```

Or if you want to store the values in a list (eg. `gerritlist` variable that you have):

```
gerritlist = [item[0] for item in gerrits]
```

Comment: ,this gives a list,i dont need a list,please see my expected output

Comment: The first line of code I have gives you a string output. Try it. Also, you should be careful not to call your 'EXPECTED OUTPUT' as a 'space separated list' if you definitely do not want a list. The second piece of code I provided gives you the option to get your values in a list, which gives you more power and control over what you want to do with the query output.

Comment: got it,does doing a print add a new line "\n" character ?

Comment: You can do `print 'string_to_print',` to avoid the newline character (that's a comma (`,`) at the end of the statement if it's hard to see)

Comment: @vk1011 - I still see a new line character getting appended?is there a way to explictly remove it from the final print

Comment: You could try this: `print 'string_to_print'.rstrip('\r\n')`. This strips off any newline characters at the end

Answer (score 0):

Following would work but am not sure about the new line part,may be others can respond with a better way

```
def listtostring(list):
  gerrits = ''    
  if len(list):
    value = len(list) - 2
    gerrits += list[value]
    for i in range(1, len(list)):   
      value -= 1
      gerrits += ' ' + list[value]
  else :
    print "No gerrits in list to parse"
  return gerrits 

for row in gerrits:
    for gerrit in row:
        gerritlist.append(gerrit)               
gerritlist_str = listtostring(gerritlist)
print gerritlist_str
```